# Wait until Azure Storage Container is deleted

Tags: azure, powershell

I am trying to delete and recreate an Azure storage container for migration purposes as it seems to delete quicker than just removing every single blob in the container. Here is the code:

```
Remove-AzureRMStorageContainer -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup -StorageAccountName "s1" -Name "c1" -Force;

while (Get-AzureRMStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -StorageAccountName "s1" | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "c1" })
{
    Start-Sleep -s 30
}

New-AzureRMStorageContainer  -ResourceGroup $ResourceGroup -StorageAccountName "s1" -Name "c1";
```

Unfortunately this fails with the error message:

```
New-AzureRMStorageContainer : The specified container is being deleted. Try operation later
```

Is there a better way to check whether the storage account has been fully removed from Azure, or will i have to go back to not deleting the container but rather the blobs inside it?

Comment: How did you delete the container? Could you provide the complete script?

Comment: I added the remove part of the script, the rest of the script is irrelevant to the question as it is working with SQL databases not blob storage.

Comment: just try creating again if it fail and loop that